# Visual Studio performance profiling WOW64 error

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio 2012 RC1 running on Windows 7 64bit operating system using the .NET Framework version 4.5 and trying to performance profile a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) project, but it is giving me the error:

`WOW64 processes is not supported by this version of the profiling tools.`

What is the way to make this work? I remember profiling just fine in VS 2010 and sometimes this shows up.

Comment: It sounds like the Visual Studio 2012 RC1 does not support profiling.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have VS2005 install by any chance, cause that would make sense then; because the profiling gives the exact same error.

MSDN:

> If you try to use the Visual Studio Team System 2005 profiling tools
>   in sampling mode on a computer that has a 64-bit operating system, you
>   will see the following error:
>
> Profiling WOW64 processes is not supported by this version of the
>   profiling tools.

If not VS2005 problem, then it's more than likely you are setting some "Optimization" in your build or test process that is causing it not to be able to interact with 64-bit Process.

Possible links to look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952405.aspx

The semantics off it - is that the Profiler is 32-bit and the process 64-bit. Not sure how that is possible.

Extra Read from Forum, where user had similar problem in Vs2010:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsprofiler/thread/cba7ee2f-661b-4026-b5c8-d4b27e7e7055/

Comment: No I don't have VS2005. I have VS2010 installed for the SQL Server 2012. It doesn't have templates for C# project: all database projects. I have Team Foundation Server 2012 RC1 that was released recently.